# Uncaught [CKEDITOR.editor] The instance "html" already exists

Tags: ckeditor

I have a problem with loading CKEDITOR. I have made everything like described here: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration But anyway i'm getting an error (Google Chrome 4.x) Uncaught [CKEDITOR.editor] The instance "html" already exists.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/engine/jq.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/engine/cke/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/engine/cke/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<textarea class="jquery_ckeditor" name="html" id="html" rows="10">text</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (CKEDITOR.instances['html']) { CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['html']); // with or without this line of code - rise an error }
    CKEDITOR.replace('html');
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, well. I have the same problem.
Ans as I can see, no answer either.

Answer (score 7):

check this:

```js
if (CKEDITOR.instances['html']) { 
    delete CKEDITOR.instances['html'] 
};

CKEDITOR.replace('html');
```

Answer (score 4):

remove `class='ckeditor'` as it's triggering the automatic replacement system.

Comment: What will be the effect? How will it help?

Comment: OMG, that worked for me. I think it just loads ckeditor on elements with class `ckeditor`, and your attempt to load editor will be to referred as second attempt and will fail. If you wrap your `$(selector).ckeditor()` in try/catch like `try { $(selector).ckeditor(); } catch(err) { console.log(err); }`, then it will start with errors in console and you will see that it has already loaded default ckeditor and says, that it cant create new instance.

Answer (score 4):

using the jquery ckeditor adapter - I was able to reinitialize ckeditor textareas in ajax content using this function.

```
function initCKEditor() {
    $('.wysiwyg').ckeditor(function(e){
            delete CKEDITOR.instances[$(e).attr('name')];
        },{
            toolbar:
                [
                    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Paste','PasteFromWord','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Link','-','Maximize','-','Source']
                ],
            skin: 'office2003'
        }
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same error, getting it with the jQuery adapter though. Check the class of the textarea. As far as i can tell all text areas with class 'ckeditor' are automatically converted to editors. So either don't bother setting it with javascript or change the class.

Answer (score 1):

http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery has a fix if you are using jQuery

// remove editor from the page
$('textarea').ckeditor(function(){
this.destroy();
});

Comment: Wouldn't that just remove it from the page immediately after creating it?

Answer (score 0):

Your page has a html container, try renaming your textarea ?

```
<textarea class="jquery_ckeditor" name="editor" id="editor" rows="10">text</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me: in an Ajax view, having two controls

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.offreJob.profile, new { @class = "input_text_area_nofloat", @style = "width:590px", @id = "ck_profile" })
```

and

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.offreJob.description_job, new { @class = "input_text_area_nofloat", @style = "width:590px", @id = "ck_description" })
```

I use the following script:

```
        <script>
        if (CKEDITOR.instances['ck_profile']) {
            delete CKEDITOR.instances['ck_profile'];
        }
        CKEDITOR.replace('ck_profile');

        if (CKEDITOR.instances['ck_description']) {
            delete CKEDITOR.instances['ck_description'];
        }
        CKEDITOR.replace('ck_description');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works, it worked for me.

for(html in CKEDITOR.instances['html')

{

CKEDITOR.instances[html ].destroy();

}

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9862#no1

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances["your_textarea"]; 
if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
```